# How import and print CSV values based on current date?

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file that is a shifts schedule with dates, hours and names. Any ideas how I can extract the names based on the current date / time? The CSV looks like this:

```
...
14 Oct 2015, 02, 12:00 - 18:00, 6, "", "John Doe", "Joe Smith"
14 Oct 2015, 03, 18:00 - 00:00, 6, "Jenny Roe", "", "Henry Smith"
15 Oct 2015, 01, 00:00 - 06:00, 6, "Jake Blake", "Bob Ford", ""
...
```

What I need is to run the code and print the names of people that are **scheduled for a next shift** like:

```
Jenny Roe
Henry Smith
```

I know that I can load the file as an array like this:

```
<?php
$csv = array();
$lines = file('schedule.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
?>
```

Or print it as a text:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("schedule.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
$line_of_text = fgets($file);
print $line_of_text . "<BR>";
  }
fclose($file);
?>
```

Now, I wonder which approach would be better to start with? If anyone can help me solve this I promise that I will learn PHP finally (doh!) and post a reply here some day as a proof.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to do something like this:

```
$currentDate = new DateTime(); //we create an object with the current time

$file = fopen("schedule.csv","r");

$results = array();

//we loop through the file, each line will be an array containing each fields
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //we create an array that has three elements: the start time, the "-" and the endtime of the shifts
    $shiftTime = explode(" ", $data[2]); 
    //We create two datetime objects that mark the beginning of the shift and the end of the shift
    $startShift = dateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y H:i", $data[0] . " " . $shiftTime[0]);
    $endShift = dateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y H:i", $data[0] . " " . $shiftTime[2]);

    //We compare the two previously created objects to the current date and if 
    //the current date is between the start of the shift and the end of the shift, 
    //we know that person is scheduled to work.
    if($currentDate >= $startShift && $currentDate <= $endShift)
        $results[] = $data;
}
```

I've added comments in the code to explain what I did.

UPDATE: In answer to Totalizator's inquiry, here's a more detailed explanation of what my final "If" statement actually does. First and foremost, there was a typo in the name of the variable which I've corrected... it should be read "results" and not "result". Anyway, the object of the final "if" statement is to determine if a person should be working as we speak. The "as we speak" part of the equation is contained within the $currentDate variable that we created on the first line of the script. Next, we create two more timestamps named $startShift and $endShift which determine when a person's shift starts and when it ends. All we have to do now is to determine if the $currentDate falls somewhere between $startShift and $endShift which is what the condition of the if does.

After that, if $currentDate actually does fall between $startShift and $endShift, we store the current line in a separate array that I named $results so that at the end of the loop, $results will only contain the lines of the people who should be working right now.

To further explain, when you do

```
$results[] = $data
```

It actually appends the content of $data at the end of the $results array. So in the end, you'll have something like this:

```
$results[0] => array(14 oct 2015, 02, 12:00 - 18:00, 6, "", "John Doe" ...) 
$results[1] => array(15 oct 2015, 01, 18:00 - 00:00, 6, "Jenny Roe", ...)
$results[2] => array(16 oct 2015, 02, 00:00 - 06:00, 6, "Jane Doe", ...)
```

So there you have it. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thank you! This looks neat. I can understand the way you did it but what is not quite clear to me is the `$results = array();` in the beginning (what it stands for?)and in the final `if` - (`$result[] = $data;`) as how do I print the output in this example?

Comment: I added some explanation to the post. If things are still unclear, don't hesitate to ask again.

Comment: Just like I expected but still, it got me confused. Thanks! The problem is that I have trouble populating the `$results`. The `schedule.csv` contains valid entries, `$startShift` and `$endShift` gets populated OK but when it comes to the `if` statement, nothing can be read `$results`-just an empty `Array ()`. Are you sure that I can compare time when `$currentData` is a Unix Timestamp and other values are like DateTime Objects? I have added `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` to make sure that the time generated is right and I have tried `$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u');`-no go.

Comment: You're right, I might have been mistaken with my $currentDate. Have you tried `$currentDate = new DateTime();`, this should create a dateTime object with a value of "now()" (as in the system's current date and time). This will then allow you to use the comparison in my final "if" with the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help Osuwariboy! It felt like an uphill struggle but it works, finally. Thanks to you.

I'll try to fully describe the case with solution:

I have **schedule.csv** file formatted like this (date, unused number, shift time, shift lenght, names (up to 6):

```
...
01 Oct 2015 ,65 ,07:00 - 15:00 ,8 ,"","John Doe","Joe Smith","Martin Taylor","Henry Smith","Mike Miller"
01 Oct 2015 ,22 ,15:00 - 23:00 ,8 ,"","Bob Ford","Sarah Smith","Jack Williams","",""
01 Oct 2015 ,11 ,23:00 - 7:00 ,8 ,"","","Jenny Roe","Adam Davis","Jake Blake",""
02 Oct 2015 ,21 ,07:00 - 19:00 ,12 "Antonio Garcia","John Doe","Joe Smith","","Henry Smith","Mike Miller"
02 Oct 2015 ,22 ,19:00 - 07:00 ,12 ,"","Bob Ford","Sarah Smith","Jack Williams","",""
02 Oct 2015 ,11 ,07:00 - 15:00 ,8 ,"","","Jenny Roe","Adam Davis","Jake Blake",""
...
```

The main issue here is that I'm looking for people scheduled not for the current, but for the **next shift**. The shifts are 8h (regular) or 12h (weekends **AND** some random days). Based on this I can't simply look 8 or 12 hours ahead as this creates various issues like:

- looking 8h ahead at the beginning of 12h shift (shows same shift)
- looking 12h ahead near the end of 8h shift (skips the next one)

There has been an issue also with the shift date, where eg. `01 Oct 2015 23:00 - 7:00` is 1 Oct for start and 2 Oct when it ends.

Based on the tips from **Osuwariboy** I came up with the following solution:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw'); //we set the current timezone to match the time from our schedule

$currentDate = new DateTime();
$currentDateRegular = new DateTime(); //object with the time 8h ahead 
$currentDateWeekend = new DateTime(); //object with the time 12h ahead

$currentDateRegular->modify('+8 hours');
$currentDateWeekend->modify('+12 hours');

$file = fopen("schedule.csv","r");

$results = array();
$resultsFinal = array();
$resultsDiff = array();
$resultsDiffWeekend = array();

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //we create an array that has four elements: the start time, the "-", the endtime 
    //of the shifts, and an empty one (not needed)
    $shiftTime = explode(" ", $data[2]);
    //we create an object with a shift date
    $shiftDate = $data[0];
    //we create an object with a shift lenght time (8 or 12 hours)
    $shiftDiff = $data[3];
    //we create an object with a shift start time *including* date
    $startShift = dateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y H:i", $data[0] . " " . $shiftTime[0]);
    //we create same object as above to modify it with the shift lenght time
    $startShiftTemp = dateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y H:i", $data[0] . " " . $shiftTime[0]);
    //we create an oject with a shift end time *including* date - that may be different
    //from the start time eg. 23:00 - 7:00 (next day)
    $endShift = $startShiftTemp->modify('+' . $shiftDiff . " " . 'hours');


    //we compare the previously created objects three times: to the current date, date 8h ahead and 12h
    //ahead, then if the current date is between the start of the shift and the end of the shift,  
    //we know who is scheduled to work
    if($currentDate >= $startShift && $currentDate <= $endShift) {
    $results = $data;
    }
    if($currentDateRegular >= $startShift && $currentDateRegular <= $endShift) {
    $resultsDiff = $data;
    }
    if($currentDateWeekend >= $startShift && $currentDateWeekend <= $endShift) {
    $resultsDiffWeekend = $data;
    }
    //the most important part here: if the results for the current date are equal with the results for the 
    //date with the time 8h ahead (not what we want), that means that the final results should be with the 
    //names for the date 12h ahead from the current date (next shift - we want this)
    if($results == $resultsDiff) {
    $resultsFinal = $resultsDiffWeekend;
    }
    //if the results for the current date are not equal with the results for the date with the time 8h ahead 
    //from now (next shift - we want this) that means that the final results should be with the names for 
    //shift 8h ahead from the current date
    if($results != $resultsDiff) {
    $resultsFinal = $resultsDiff;
    }
}

//we print the results line by line, but only when there is some data (to avoid creating empty ones as there is 
//not always six people during the shift)
if(!empty($resultsFinal[4]))
    print_r($resultsFinal[4] . "<BR>");
if(!empty($resultsFinal[5]))
        print_r($resultsFinal[5] . "<BR>");
if(!empty($resultsFinal[6]))
        print_r($resultsFinal[6] . "<BR>");
if(!empty($resultsFinal[7]))
        print_r($resultsFinal[7] . "<BR>");
if(!empty($resultsFinal[8]))
    print_r($resultsFinal[8] . "<BR>");
if(!empty($resultsFinal[9]))
        print_r($resultsFinal[9] . "<BR>");
?>
```

Maybe it's not the most beautiful or clean code but hey, it seems to be working under every condition. I hope somebody will find it useful too.